# to_string() C++ Time Complexity

Tags: c++

I wrote a code to convert integer to string values in C++. I wanted to know the time complexity of my code.

```
int n;
cin>>n;
cout<<to_string(n);
```

Can anyone tell me the exact time complexity of the **to_string()** function in C++?

Comment: It is unknown.  You would need to check your implementation to find out.

Comment: Usually, with such functions you don't need to analyze time complexity. Also you don't need it in that case, `cout` can already handle `int`.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What is the *actual* underlying problem leading to this question? Please always ask about the actual, underlying and original problem directly. Otherwise this is just an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Time complexity isn't a particularly useful metric until you have large numbers for N. In the case of an `int`, If you count digits, N is going to be at most 20, a pretty small number, for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Side note: The code in `>>` and `<<` plus the waiting for IO is likely going to completely bury the cost of `to_string`.

Comment: Arguably it's `O(1)` because the length of the 'input' to to_string is fixed.

Comment: By the way, a little nitpicking about your `stl` tag: The STL stands for [the Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), and despite its name it's not the same as the C++ standard library. Parts of the STL was used as a base for the first C++ standard library, and other parts have been added later in one form or another. But they are still not the same.

Comment: To solve your problem you you need to examine the source code for the <<, >>, and to_string() operations.  No one can answer this question without examining that code.  I'd suggest that if you truly need to know, you find the source code for *your platform/implementation* and bring that back here if you don't know how to measure big O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of implementation of to_string in the specific library. We can try to compute approximate complexity of such algorithm

O([log10(n)])

where [] is upper bound of number

Actually
log(10)+1 is number of digits in the number and we will spend about constant time for each digit.

Note: adopt [log10(1)] as 1. to_string(1) will spend a constant time

More one note: in most cases like

```
for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    std::cout << std::to_string(i) << std::endl;
}
```

we should take complexity std::to_string as O(1) and overall complexity of such cycle is m*O(1) -> O(m)
where `m` is the cycle iterations count.

Comment: where `n` is what?

Comment: n is the number:

`int n;`